# UNIX command to delete all JPEG files missing file extension

Tags: unix

UNIX command to delete all the JPEG files in the current directory. None of the files have extensions so simply using `rm *.jpg` will not work.

Comment: _Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers._ There are other sites in the [SE network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) better suited for this kind of questions.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you want to check the content of a file (with no extension) to verify that it's a jpg image before deleting it?

Answer (score 1):

Using `file` and some string equality can get you there:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# loop through files
for f in *; do
  # check if output of file cmd has "jpeg/jpg/jpe/jfif" in it
  if [[ $(file -i --extension "$f") = *"jpeg/jpg/jpe/jfif"* ]]; then
    echo "$f is a jpeg!"
    rm "$f"
  fi
done
```

Comment: i need unix command

Comment: This is a shell script, it will work the same way.